# Woocommerce/Wordpress Product Page strange layout

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress with WooCommerce, I've made a custom theme (so possibly part of the problem) but I've based it off the default Wordpress theme.

When I click on a product page that doesn't have ANY pictures, the layout is fine and it shows a blank picture image.

When I then add an image to the same product, refresh the page product page, the layout style for the tabs disappears and instead the tabs are displayed as text with no style. It appears that the `::before` and `::after` code is present on the "no image" tabs, but when I add an image they disappear!

The style for the image also changes, the size goes crazy and there is no padding on the right of the image so the description/title/add to cart touches the image!

Site: http://frenchies-boutique.wadessolutions.com

The site was build around the Twenty Fifteen theme.

**single-product.php**

```php
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single products.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_sidebar hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

**product-image.php**

```php
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Image
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.14
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post, $woocommerce, $product;

?>
<div class="images">

    <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

        $image_title    = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_caption  = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt;
        $image_link     = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        $image          = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), array(
            'title' => $image_title,
            'alt'   => $image_title
        ) );

        $attachment_count = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );

        if ( $attachment_count > 0 ) {
            $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
        } else {
            $gallery = '';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_caption, $image ), $post->ID );

    } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', wc_placeholder_img_src(), __( 'Placeholder', 'woocommerce' ) ), $post->ID );

    }
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>

</div>
```

thanks

Comment: Could you provide some of your template code relative to the issue? And what is the parent theme?

Comment: I've updated the question respectively.